# Haskell implicit String polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

How can I reduce effort in writing scripts that need to convert between different string representations?

For example, how to create a polymorphic setting where `getContents` and `putStrLn` do not need additional "glue code" to use functions like one below (derived from `Network.HTTP.Types`)?

```
pathElementsFromUri :: B.ByteString -> [T.Text]
```

How can I leverage locale to completely avoid I/O conversions?

Complete example where correct namespaces are needed to do simple things. Persons new to Haskell don't get things like this right at first try.

```
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Data.Foldable
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = B.getContents >>= printout

printout = traverse_ T.putStrLn . pathElements
pathElements = fst . decodePath . extractPath
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What did you have to write to implement this? What made it hard? What sort of type signatures are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: It seems hard to do this completely seamlessly. One problem is that once you make functions polymorphic enough to work on all stringlike types, you start getting ambiguities at intermediate steps instead, e.g. what stringlike type should be chosen in the middle for `getContents >>= putStrLn`? Although I wonder if one could abuse the `default` and `ExtendedDefaultRules` mechanisms enough to handle this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check out the [string-conversions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-conversions) package.

There is a completely polymorphic `convertString` function to convert to and from any of the major string types. Also, there are less polymorphic `to...` and `from...` functions.

E.g.

```
bs :: ByteString
bs = ...

txt :: Text
txt = ...

putStrLn $ convertString bs <> convertString txt
```